# Creating a Nested Dictionary from For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a new dictionary from existing data. I'm not sure the best way to explain so here is an example:

I have the following data:

```
list_1 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']

dict_1 = {'key_1': {1: 'data1', 2: 'aa'},
          'key_2': {1: 'data2', 2: 'aa'},
          'key_3': {1: 'data3', 2: 'cc'},
          'key_4': {1: 'data4', 2: 'bb'},
          'key_5': {1: 'data5', 2: 'bb'},
          'key_6': {1: 'data6', 2: 'cc'}}
```

I want to loop through list_1 and dict_1 and if the item in list_1 matches the second key value pair in dict_1 it adds it to the new dict.

So the output would be something like:

```
{'aa': {{1: 'data1', 2: 'aa'},
        {1: 'data2', 2: 'aa'}},
'bb': {{1: 'data4', 2: 'bb'},
       {1: 'data5', 2: 'bb'}},
'cc': {{1: 'data3', 2: 'cc'},
       {1: 'data6', 2: 'cc'}}}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict` for this.

Note your desired output includes sets of dictionaries. I assume you want lists of dictionaries.

It also does not appear you *need* to use `list_1`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_1 = {'key_1': {1: 'data1', 2: 'aa'},
          'key_2': {1: 'data2', 2: 'aa'},
          'key_3': {1: 'data3', 2: 'cc'},
          'key_4': {1: 'data4', 2: 'bb'},
          'key_5': {1: 'data5', 2: 'bb'},
          'key_6': {1: 'data6', 2: 'cc'}}

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in dict_1.items():
    d[v[2]].append(v)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'aa': [{1: 'data1', 2: 'aa'}, {1: 'data2', 2: 'aa'}],
             'bb': [{1: 'data4', 2: 'bb'}, {1: 'data5', 2: 'bb'}],
             'cc': [{1: 'data3', 2: 'cc'}, {1: 'data6', 2: 'cc'}]})
```